Divided power structure on $E_\infty$-algebras?
Let $A$ be a simplicial commutative ring, then it is known that the ideal of elements of degree $\ge1$ in the associated CDGA has a "DG divided power structure," which induces a divided power structure on the ideal of elements of degree $\ge1$ in the graded-commutative ring $\pi_*A$. I am trying to interpret this as saying something like "the infinitesimal thickening $\operatorname{Spec}\pi_0A\to\operatorname{Spec}N(A)$ of spectral schemes has the structure of a PD-thickening," where $N$ is the forgetful from simplicial commutative rings to $E_\infty$-rings.
This suggests the following question: let $f:A\to B$ be a morphism of connective $E_\infty$-rings in spectra or $D(\mathbb{Z})$ inducing a surjection on $\pi_0$. Is there a suitable notion of "divided power structure on $\operatorname{fib}(f)$?" I want there to be an automatic PD-structure on $\operatorname{fib}(N(A)\to\pi_0(A))$ for $A$ a simplicial commutative ring. As well, the blunt notion "$\pi_*\operatorname{fib}(f)\to\pi_*A$ is a quasi-ideal and is given a PD-structure" (it is not clear to me if the first condition is automatic) seems "not coherent enough," though I don't know any formal list of "properties I want" that would exclude this.
It seems to me any kind of animation procedure would just spit out something in the strictly commutative rather than the $E_\infty$-setting, and divided powers are too nonlinear to be tractable operadically, so I don't see what tools are available here.
I am doubtful about this, since I don't even know what structure on $\operatorname{fib}(f)$ should correspond to its being the fiber of a $\pi_0$-surjection of connective $E_\infty$-rings (though see the discussion here: there is a notion of Smith ideal for $A_\infty$-rings, and the paper of David White linked there has a notion which may be suitable.) (Correction: Smith ideals for the $E_\infty$-setting are handled by Theorem A in the paper of White and Yau linked in the same answer.) But I am posting this in the hopes someone knows something like this.

@LoganHyslop $\pi_(A)$ will be the free graded PD-ring on one generator in that case, that is generated by symbols $x^n/n!$ rather than the free ring, e.g. Lemma 3.1.2 of Lurie's "Derived Algebraic Geometry." The PD-structure on $\pi_(A)$ I've seen attributed to Cartan in "Algèbre d'Eilenberg-Maclane et homotopie," though I'm not seeing exactly where. "On The Homotopy Of Simplicial Algebras Over An Operad" by Fresse or "Divided Power Algebras and Chain Complexes" by Richter contain slightly stronger results.

ah yeah, you’re right, I was mixing something up in my head, oops.
